# How can I insert multiple answer with radio button?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am making quiz application using it. I am using Laravel 5.5 and I am stuck in between saving answer of quiz.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($questions as $question)
            @if($id == $question->category_id)
                <legend> Quiz Of {{ $question->category->title }}</legend>
                <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/store-answer') }}" class="crud-submit" id="quiz_module">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="{{ $question->category_id }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="{{ $question->id }}">
                        <h4> 
                            Question {{ $question->id }}
                        </h4>
                        <h3>
                            {{ $question->question }}
                        </h3><brx`>
                        <h5>
                            &emsp;<input type="radio" name="answer" class="form-check-input"  value="{{ $question->option_a }}">{{ $question->option_a }}<br>
                            &emsp;<input type="radio" name="answer" class="form-check-input" value="{{ $question->option_b }}">{{ $question->option_b }}<br>
                            &emsp;<input type="radio" name="answer" class="form-check-input" value="{{ $question->option_c }}">{{ $question->option_c }}<br>
                            &emsp;<input type="radio" name="answer" class="form-check-input" value="{{ $question->option_d }}">{{ $question->option_d }}<br>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                </form>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.5/validator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function()
    {
        var radioValue = $("input[name='answer']:checked").val();
        //$(".crud-submit").click(function (e) {
            // e.preventDefault();
            var form_action = $("#quiz_module").find("form").attr("action");
            var user_id = $("input[name='user_id']").val();
            var category_id = $("input[name='category_id']").val();
            var question_id = $("input[name='question_id']").val();
            //var radioValue = $("input[name='answer']:checked").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/store-answer',
                data: { user_id: user_id, category_id: category_id, question_id: question_id, radioValue: radioValue },
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
            });
        //});
    });
});
</script>
```

I am fetching all the questions from database. And Per Question there are 4 options available. I want to save the answer in database when user chooses any of the options. I am trying to save that using ajax, but some how it does not work, will anyone please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "some how it not works"? what's the error you're getting

Comment: My data is not submit in database, It gives 500 Error

Comment: See I got this error https://prnt.sc/p3x3z3

Comment: try to add it at the first of your js code `$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
`

Comment: Then I got `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/store-answer 419 (unknown status)` this error

Comment: any one help please?

Comment: @amindevloper can you share your backend code?

Comment: ya sure, which code should I share?>

Comment: The code that will receive ajax and insert it to db

Comment: Reformatted code

Comment: will you help me for this question??
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57876933/how-can-i-get-seprate-quiestion-id-in-foreach-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to used below code in blade file.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Comment: will you help me for this question??
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57876933/how-can-i-get-seprate-quiestion-id-in-foreach-loop